# SQL Server 2012 installation remove enforce password policy

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to install SQL Server 2012 in mixed mode I need to provide a simple password for `sa` login, but as per password policy it needs to be strong. Is there a way to provide a simple password. Can I remove enforce password policy while installing SQL Server 2012?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We're not general software tech support.

Comment: Sorry for this question, will try to get help from other means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable password policy after installation for sure.But during installation ,you can't do that.A [quick search](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/00549f62-57ce-4720-8432-0194e7623bc9/disable-password-policy-check-while-installing-sql-server-express-r2?forum=sqlexpress) yielded me below

> CHECK_POLICY cannot be globally disabled.  The policy definition is inherited from the Windows server or from the domain.  (So, if the machine where SQL Express is installed has NO password policy and is not connected to a domain, you might get away with a weak password.)
>
> CHECK_POLICY is an option that has to be specified for every SQL Server login (including 'sa') that should not enforce password policies.